# How to find a source file used in process.binding('..') in node source code?

Tags: node.js, node-modules

I want to see source code of the file mentioned in `process.binding()` statement in nodeJS source code, have seen similar question on stackoverflow but most of them answers to specific cases like fs etc.

I want explanation based on which I should be able to find any file mentioned in `process.bindings()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since this question is lying here for very long I decided to give it another try to find the answer and found one very nice presentation online.

[Process.bindings presentation](http://lanceball.com/process-bindings/#/)

To summaries this, process.bindings() binds the javascript object with the C++ object which exposes the C++ functions to be executed from javascript, essentially it creates a javascript wrapper around the C++ functions to make it available from NodeJS.

To find which C++ function is bound to which javascript function you can dig into NodeJS source tree here [NodeJs source tree](https://github.com/nodejs/node/tree/master/src) . Names are straightforward to map with core module names and look for signature  `env->SetMethod(target, "<modulename>", <C++ function name>);`

Example:  `env->SetMethod(target, "stat", Stat);`

Comment: Below blog has more details on how it works.                                      https://akshaynaik.net/2020-03-15-Mystery-Behind-process.binding('')/